# how to send image via email in android?

Tags: android, email

I am developing an application in which i have to send an image via email, I tried with        
`Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);`

```
            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "xyz@gmal.com");
            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "message");
            emailIntent.setType("image/png");

            ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<Uri>();

            uris.add(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.drawable.a));

            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);

            startActivity(emailIntent);
```

but its giving me as **gmail has stopped unfortunately**.How can I send an image via email,
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Get the image storage path by using the file,

```
 File img = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Android/data/"+getApplicationContext().getPackageName()+"/", imagename+".png");
```

Convert that file path in to Uri

```
Uri imageuri = Uri.fromFile(img);
```

Send the image via email using

```
Intent send_img = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                                        send_img.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "xyz@gmal.com"); 
                                        send_img.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "email_subject");
                                        send_img.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageuri);
                                        send_img.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "message");  
                                        send_img.setType("text/plain");
                                        send_img.setType("image/png");
 startActivity(Intent.createChooser(send_img, "Send Email..."));
```